# How to select multiple elements by position with XPath?

Tags: html, xpath, lxml, xpath-2.0

I have the following XPath code that selects elements on the following website:

XPath code:

```
//div[@title='buyer-info']
```

website: http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html

To select the first element of the returned elements, I would use:

```
(//div[@title='buyer-info'])[1]
```

I would like to select the 4th to the last elements. I imagine the XPath code would be something like:

```
(//div[@title='buyer-info'])[4:last()]
```

This is however not a valid XPath query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check the [`position()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) value:

> The position function returns a number equal to the context position from the expression evaluation context.

```
(//div[@title='buyer-info'])[position() >= 4]
```